# Calling javac from php

Tags: java, php, javac

I have a HelloWorld.java located on my server, and I'd like to compile this program using "javac" within php.

So, I have the following code

```
<?php 
exec("javac HelloWorld.java", $array); 
print_r($array);
?>
```

And the output is

```
Array ( )
```

What am I doing wrong? javac.exe is located in the same spot this php file is.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to compile Java from a PHP file? This seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: I'm trying to allow a user to write java code and see the output all on a website. Any better ideas to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should surely help you

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-commandline/index.html

The output parameter gets only standard output, if you need error output too, don't forget to redirect it. 
If the output parameter is still empty after an execution and if it shouldn't, you must be in this case.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Or

use passthrough. It looks similar to execute.

Read the links provided.

Something like this:

```
<?php
# ...
# (function stuff)
ob_start();
passthru("php myscript.php, $result");
$content_grabbed=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

if($result=0){
 echo '<div>',$content_grabbed,'</div>';
}_
# (more function stuff)
# ...
?>
```

I don't know about drawbacks that this method might have. Maybe and increased overhead? Anyway I was happy to circumvent the problem with it.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Comment: can you give me an example of how to get the error? I'm not overly familiar with php, and I'm not understanding what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I ran this and changed "myscript.php" to the php file I am using. I get no output. Does this mean there are no errors? I still don't see the HelloWorld.class as expected.

Comment: Can i know what is the purpose of calling the java file.? it will not be just for echoing. Do some action in the java file like creating a file. So we can know that java is called or not. returning values from java and print it in php am not sure how to do that.:(

Comment: I cannot run the java file though unless I first compile it with javac. And javac isn't making the .class file.

Comment: did you run your java program in java enviornment. did it compile properly ?  why dont you compile it seperately and call java file name ? hmmmm i think you trying to be a hacker

Comment: what? a hacker? my program works fine. I'm just trying to create a "learn java" site...

Answer (score 3):

javac has no output on successful compilation. What would you expect in `$array`?

Comment: true. however commands such as "java -version" also produces an output of "Array ( )"

Comment: `java -version` outputs on stderr not stdout, so it wouldn't get caught in that array.

Answer (score 0):

Reese Moore is correct that **javac** has no output when successful, if you want output from this, try adding '-verbose' to the parameters, what you probably want to do is check for success, use the return value parameter for this purpose.

Add *2>&1* to the command to get the error stream in to the standard output (assuming bash is the underlying shell).

```
<?php
exec("javac HelloWorld.java 2>&1", $output, $resultCode);

if ($resultCode) {
  echo "Result: " . $resultCode . "\n";
  echo implode("\n", $output);
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm getting the following output: Result: -1073741515

Comment: It might be because I didn't initialise it, as it's a pass by reference variable.

Add, before the exec() call:

$resultCode = 0;

Comment: now I'm not getting any output. However, I don't see the HelloWorld.class file created. Any ideas?

Comment: The code I wrote only generates output if there is an error.

If you add an else-clause to it, then you can display something to indicate success.

if ($resultCode) {
  echo "Result: " . $resultCode . "\n";
  echo implode("\n", $output);
} else {
  echo "Success\n";
}

Comment: Yes, there is success. However a ".class" file is not generated. Why could this be?