# Running Java through server

Tags: java, php, html, javac

I have a website. I'd like to do the following:

Have an input box that the user can type a java program. Then, they can press "Run" and it spits out standard output. How can I achieve this?

I tried thinking about using exec("javac $filename") in php and just compile and run the java program, but that doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

I am trying to make a "learn Java" site, and I need the user to be able to play with code by typing into spaces on my website. I just can't figure out how to go about running Java using php, html, or things like that.

Comment: somewhat related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208096/calling-javac-from-php

Comment: Running Java through a server would ruin motherboards(s).

Comment: @Hamish I thought you were taking a stab at Java performance, but perhaps the joke is about pouring liquid on electronics ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Do *not* do this!** Get people to run an applet or something. In addition to the security implications, your server would also likely grind to a halt.
2. If you ignore (1) just use a proper app server and get people to write their own jsps (make sure caching is turned off). It's a very easy bit of file IO.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it could be done, along the lines of what you've described too. However this is a massive security risk. You don't want to allow unknown/untrusted people to be able to execute arbitrary code on your server. At the very least you'd want to be very careful with this idea, and possibly better still, modify the idea so that arbitrary code can not be entered, and executed.

Comment: I would just like to let you know that there is no need to manually sign your posts with your name because your name is already visible on the post. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed/5038#5038) for more info. I edited it out for you.

Comment: I didn't sign my post with my name. With regards to the security risk, I am only using basic code and the user will only implement functions, they will not be allowed to import anything so there is no way they could do anything crazy. Since yous say it can be done, can you describe a way?

Comment: @Robert: Sorry, I was talking to @Peter. :)

Comment: you don't need to import to run arbitrary java code.  you can explicitly name the package in the code.  java.io.File f = new java.io.File();

Answer (score 0):

You might look into Quercus. It's a java web server that runs PHP. You might be able to run the java code right in the web server then.
http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/